# Are some Enterprise Library Application Blocks becoming obsolete?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, enterprise-library, daab

With the introduction of newer paradigms in ASP.Net, are some of the Application Blocks in **Enterprise Library** becoming obsolete? For example, look at following:

- *ASP.Net Membership, Role & Profile provider* as opposed to *Security Application Block*
- *LINQ to SQL & Entity Framework* as opposed to *Data Access Application Block*

Are the aforementioned Application Blocks still relevant? Can someone illustrate when and why would one use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a producer of Microsoft Enterprise Library, I felt it was important to explain the concept of "*carefully managed deprecation*". So, I've posted an [extended response](http://blogs.msdn.com/agile/archive/2011/04/08/on-deprecation.aspx) on my blog.